# Aptana: which one is better? Standalone Version or Eclipse Plug-in Version?

Tags: php, ide, recommendation-engine, aptana

i'm new to ubuntu and wanna choose my php/javascript IDE.
there is two options for download:

> Standalone Version

and

> Eclipse Plug-in Version

the **performance** and not being **too hight-weight** is important to me.

which one shall i download?

what's the benefit of downloading it as a Eclipse plugin? does it help me to use it beside PDT or it's not recommended to do so?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The benefit of downloading it as a plugin is that you can integrate it with your existing eclipse install. If you already have a lot of other plugins installed, that might be useful to you.

If you want Eclipse to be as fast as possible you should just download a very basic version of Eclipse and only install the parts of Aptana that you really need. Instead of everything. Aptana usually comes with too much bloat for my taste, I always disable quite a bit in the `General -> Startup and Shutdown` section.

If you just need PDT than installing Aptana is probably your easiest way. If you also want to install cDT or something than installing a regular Eclipse package might be easier. If you want it fast, you'll have to disable some plugins either way. Aptana installs more than it needs by default.

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend [Netbeans](http://netbeans.org/) which supports php and symfony.

You should use the aptana plugin if you actually have eclipse.
The standalone version is eclipse tunned by the aptana people.

Good luck.